# JS and DOM, trying to create table

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events

I tried to create table but I can't create td in every tr, td is creating only in first td what is in table, how I can solve the problem?

// Creating div

```
var main = document.createElement("div")
main.innerHTML = ""
document.body.appendChild(main)
main.setAttribute("id", "main")
```

//Creating Icons

```
var puzzleico = document.createElement("div")
puzzleico.innerHTML = ""
document.getElementById("main").appendChild(puzzleico)
puzzleico.setAttribute("id", "puzzleico")
var puzzleico = document.getElementById("puzzleico").onclick = function() {createtable()};
```

//Creating tr and td

```
function createtable() {
//Creating Table
var table = document.createElement("table")
table.innerHTML = ""
document.body.appendChild(table)
table.setAttribute("id", "table")

for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr")
    tr.innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("table").appendChild(tr)
    tr.setAttribute("id", "tr")
    var td = document.createElement("td")
    td.innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("tr").appendChild(td)
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your answer and got what I want.

```
    //Creating tr and td
function createtable() {
    //Creating Table
    var table = document.createElement("table")
    table.innerHTML = ""
    document.body.appendChild(table)
    table.setAttribute("id", "table")

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr")
        tr.innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("table").appendChild(tr)
        tr.setAttribute("id", "tr")
        for (var v = 0; v < 50; v++) {
            var td = document.createElement("td")
            td.innerHTML = ""
            tr.appendChild(td)  
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Element `id`'s within a document [need to be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611963/can-multiple-different-html-elements-have-the-same-id-if-theyre-different-eleme). The issue here is that your `document.getElementById("tr")` will always return the first element it finds with that `id` and so, all of your `<td>` elements will be appended to the first `<tr>`.

In order to fix it you can remove the `tr.setAttribute("id", "tr")` line and use the already existing `tr` variable to append the `td` child to.

```js
function createtable() {
  //Creating Table
  var table = document.createElement("table")
  table.innerHTML = ""
  document.body.appendChild(table)
  table.setAttribute("id", "table")

  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr")
    tr.innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("table").appendChild(tr);
    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = "test"
    tr.appendChild(td)
  }
}
createtable();
```

---

The above code will work, but using the already declared variables instead of finding them again can also be applied to the `table` case. Also, `table.innerHTML = ""` doesn't add any value because the `innerHTML` is already empty when you create a new element.

```
function createtable() {
  //Creating Table
  var table = document.createElement("table");
  document.body.appendChild(table);

  for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
    var tr = document.createElement("tr");
    table.appendChild(tr);

    var td = document.createElement("td");
    td.innerHTML = "test";
    tr.appendChild(td);
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe also use the `table` variable instead of the `document.getElementById("table")`; Not necessary but function will break if you wanna make multiple tables.

Comment: @theblackgigant Yes definitely. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to create the table:

```
function createTable(){
  //Creating And Appending Child
  let table = document.createElement('table');
  document.body.appendChild(table);

  for(let i = 0; i < 50; i++){
    let tr = document.createElement('tr');
    let td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = i;
    tr.appendChild(td);
    table.appendChild(tr);
  }
}
```

Here is the link to my codepen:
https://codepen.io/prabodhpanda/pen/gOPLqYe?editors=1010

Answer (score 0):

id attribute of each element in DOM should be unique. You set same id for each tr element you create. [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) element always returns the first element match by the id. This is the reason of the issue. Your last code snippet should be:

```
function createtable() {
    //Creating Table
    var table = document.createElement("table")
    table.innerHTML = ""
    document.body.appendChild(table)
    table.setAttribute("id", "table")

    for (var i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        var tr = document.createElement("tr")
        tr.innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("table").appendChild(tr)
        tr.setAttribute("id", "tr" + i) // Check this
        var td = document.createElement("td")
        td.innerHTML = ""
        document.getElementById("tr" + i).appendChild(td) // Check this
    }
}
```

`tr.appendChild(td)` should also work if you don't need ID attribute.